# why android.support.v4.media in androidx library?

Tags: android-support-library, androidx

I am quite curious why packages android.support.v4.media and android.support.v4.media.session in the list of androidx packages, packages link: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/packages
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIiP2.png)

Could anyone explain the reason, is that because support library is still in the process of migration to androidx library?